# Combining two lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, insert

If I had two lists A and B, how can I add all the elements of B to the beginning of list A, without "emptying" the B list. I basically want to just transfer copies of B list into the beginning of A list. I'm thinking about using insert and want to double check on the syntax.

I know if I was adding it to the end it would be:

```
A.insert(A.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

so to insert it at the beginning would it be:

```
A.insert(A.begin(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

??

Comment: Did you try it?  When you did so, did it work, or did something go wrong?

Comment: You may want to consult the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

That can be achieved with one line, using the fact a list can be iterated both ways.

`copy(A.rbegin(), A.rend(), front_inserter(B));`

Complete example (`C++11` for list constructors and printing code, but answer is `C++03` valid):

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // Create lists
  std::list<char> A = {'a','b'};
  std::list<char> B = {'c','d'};

  // Insert A at the beginning of B
  copy(A.rbegin(), A.rend(), front_inserter(B));

  // Print result
  for(auto c : B)
    std::cout << c;
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a temporary copy of the list you want to append without emptying, then splice the temporary list into the original. Here is and example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::list<int> mylist;
  std::list<int>::iterator it;

  std::list<int> otherList;
  std::list<int> combinedList;

  // set some initial values:
  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i) mylist.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5
  for (int i=6; i<=10; i++) otherList.push_back(i); // 6 7 8 9 10

  std::list<int> temp = otherList;
  combinedList = mylist;
  it = combinedList.begin();

  combinedList.splice(it, temp);

  std::cout << "mylist contains:";
  for (it=combinedList.begin(); it!=combinedList.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  std::cout<<"orignal appended list:"<<std::endl;
  for(it=otherList.begin(); it!=otherList.end(); ++it)
    std::cout<<' '<<*it;
  std::cout<<'\n';

  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/e.js/Ol6Wk1